# PayPal v.zero SDK error: "Sorry we cannot connect to PayPal"

Tags: paypal, braintree

I'm testing a new feature for a site I've built for a client that uses the Braintree v.zero SDK (using the PHP SDK + a simple custom UI, not the drop-in UI) to process PayPal payments. We've tested pretty extensively in sandbox mode, and are now trying to test in production mode with small transactions; but even though I've followed the steps to "go live" in the v.zero documentation (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/accept-payments/express-checkout/ec-vzero/testing-go-live/php/), when a user clicks the button to authenticate with PayPal, the popup window that opens just shows an extremely vague error message: "Sorry we cannot connect to PayPal. Please try again in a few minutes."

Is there some way I can get more clarity into what exactly is going wrong? The access token I'm using to create the Braintree gateway on the server side is valid for production, as far as I can tell, so I don't know what else the problem could be. I've seen a couple other questions where this type of error message is mentioned, but those all seem to have been non-US developers trying to set up sandbox accounts for US companies. My client and I are both in the US, and sandbox testing worked fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this issue? We are having the same thing happening on our service...fine in Sandbox, not working in Production.

Comment: @adamgede, yes and no – I sent a very similar message to PayPal support and they were totally unhelpful, but eventually my client got in touch with Braintree support, who seemed to find some kind of configuration issue that they could fix themselves. Here's the quote from Braintree's support email:

"I’m now able to confirm that your PayPal business account is successfully hooked to your Braintree gateway. This should resolve the issue that you are currently experiencing."

Basically, I'd try contacting Braintree rather than PayPal. They fixed the problem, even if I don't understand how.